# How to manupulate the "itemDisabled" attribute of <selectOption> tag?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

consider apex pick-list as below

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:selectList id="mySelectList" size="1" onchange="manipulateOptions();">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="Option 1" itemDisabled="true"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="Option 2" itemDisabled="true"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="Option 3" itemDisabled="true"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="Option 4" itemDisabled="true"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:form>
```

Now my requirement is how do I change the value of "itemDisabled" to false by using js or jquery on onclick or onload of this vfpage

Thanks in advance